# printing a string

Tags: c

Is there any function for printing a string up to space, 
e.g.

```
char* A = "This is a string."
print(A+5);
output: is
```

I don't want printing character by character.

Comment: Certainly not, you have to write your own function

Comment: Malloc a new string the same length as the passed one.  Copy char-by-char into the new string until you find a space, then write a \0. printf the new string and then free it.

Comment: "I don't want printing character by character."  Sorry, all C functions, be they library functions or made by you, print character by character. If you don't want this, you cannot print anything using the C language.

Comment: I thought printing a string can be faster than printing each character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf("%s", buf)` prints the characters from `buf` until a null terminator is encountered: there is no way to change that behaviour.

A possible solution that does not print character-by-character, does not modify the string to be printed and uses the format specifier `%.*s` which prints the first `N` characters from a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* s = "this is a string";
    char* space_ptr = strchr(s, ' ');

    if (0 != space_ptr)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", space_ptr - s, s);
    }
    else
    {
        /* No space - print all. */
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> this

Answer (score 1):

An `istream_iterator` tokenizes on whitespace:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  const char* f = "this is a string";
  std::stringstream s(f);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> beg(s);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
  std::advance(beg, 3);
  if(beg != end)
    std::cout << *beg << std::endl;
  else
    std::cerr << "too far" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```